# How the money is paid to the IPL players?

Tags: cricket, indian-premier-league

If a player is auctioned for Rs. 14cr and he played only 3 match will he be entitled to get his entire fees or he will be paid on a prorata basis for e.g no of match played.

Answer (score 2):

If a player is *available* for a match and he is not selected in the playing XI, he will get the full match payment. In short if player is available for the entire series but he isn't picked up in any match, he will still get full payment. E.g. Rs. 14cr in this case.

Comment: any reference for this ?